# Как создать генератор потока для данного итерируемого объекта

Tags: python

Напишите функцию, которая создаёт генератор потока для итерируемого объекта (list, generator и т.д.), чьи элементы содержат позицию и значение, и отсортированны по возрастанию позиции. Генератор потока должен быть равен исходному потоку (без учёта позиции), но с интервалами заполненными нулями. Например:

```
gen = gen_stream(9, [(4,111), (7,12)])
list(gen)
### Результат:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0]
```

Индексация начинается с `0`, следовательно позиция **111** в генераторе потока = `5` (индекс `4`), позиция **12** = `8` (индекс `7`). Таким образом индексы `4` и `7` заполнены двумя элементами из итерируемого объекта, остальные индексы нулями. Для упрощения задачи элементы исходного потока отсортированны - элемент с меньшей позицией предшествует элементу с большей позицией.

Первый параметр может быть `None`, в этом случае поток должен быть бесконечным, например бесконечный поток нулей:

```
gen_stream(None, [])
```

Следующий поток начинается с `0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, ...` затем бесконечно генерируются нули:

```
gen_stream(None, [(4,111),(7,12)])
```

Функция также должна поддерживать кастомный экстрактор, который будет извлекать позицию и значение из более сложных объектов, например:

```
def day_extractor(x):
    months = [31,28,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31,30,31]
    acc = sum(months[:x[1]-1]) + x[0] - 1
    return (acc, x[2])

precipitation_days = [(3,1,4),(5,2,6)]
# 59 - ограничение потока суммой количества дней 
# в январе и феврале: 31 + 28 = 59 
list(gen_stream(59, precipitation_days, day_extractor))

# Результат:
[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`precipitation_days` имеет следующий формат: `(d,m,mm)`, где `d` - номер дня в месяце, `m` - номер месяца, `mm` - осадки в миллиметрах.

Пример:

- `(3,1,4)` - 3 января, осадки 4 mm
- `(5,2,6)` - 5 февраля, осадки 6 mm

Экстрактор передаётся как опциональный третий параметр со значением по умолчанию - лямбда функция, которая обрабатывает `(position, value)` пары, как в первом примере.

Вот что я сделал:

```
    import sys
    a=[(4,111),(7,12)]
    n = 9
    def gen_stream(n1, a1):
     if n1==None:
      b = [0 for i in range(sys.maxsize)]
     else:
      b = [0 for i in range(n1)]
     for i in range(len(a1)):
         b[a[i][0]]=a[i][1]
     for i in range(len(b)):
       yield b[i]
    for i in gen_stream(None, a):
        print(i)
```

Пока что дошёл до потока с бесконечными нулями, но функция не выполняется почему-то... И как сделать дальше с месяцами? У меня вылетает ошибка памяти, и прога жрёт много оперативы((( помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Переведите задание на русский язык.

Comment: проще спросить сразу на инглише, там народу больше чем на ру

Comment: Не делайте промежуточный список, зачем он вам? Делайте нормальный генератор, который сразу делает yield нужных данных, без их хранения. Тогда и памяти хватит и ошибок меньше будет

Answer (score 4):

Извините, решил за Вас. Задачка показалась интересной.

```py
from itertools import count

def gen_stream(n, seq, extractor=lambda x: x):
    seq = dict(map(extractor, seq))
    iterable = count() if n is None else range(n)
    for i in iterable:
        yield seq.get(i, 0)
```

Comment: Красиво, по-питоновски, ничего лишнего.

Comment: Решение красивое, но есть недостаток - первым делом упаковывает `elements` в словарь, следовательно: 1) с большой последовательностью (`list`, `generator`) съест много памяти, с бесконечным же генератором вообще работать не сможет. 2) Пока оно не сформирует словарь, выходной поток не начнётся, соответственно будет лаг на старте, продолжительность которого зависит от величины входной последовательности.

Comment: В вопросе же предполагается (как мне кажется), что эта функция должна работать как `pipe` в Unix - пропускать через себя поток данных, преобразуя его по ходу дела. Соответственно, аккумулирование данных в какое-либо хранилище, для последующей обработки здесь не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

#### Вариант №1

```
def gen_stream(size, elements, extractor=lambda x: x):
    def gen_zero():
        while True:
            yield 0

    def gen_values_with_gaps(zeros_gen):
        nonlocal cnt
        # Вынимаем очередной элемент
        for pos, val in map(extractor, elements):
            # и пишем в поток нули до тех пор, пока
            # счётчик не будет равен позиции
            # на которую надо поставить элемент
            for _ in range(pos - cnt):
                yield next(zeros_gen)
            # Когда счётчик поровнялся с нужной позицией
            # пишем в поток значение элемента
            yield val
        # После того как элементы закончились, продолжаем
        # писать в поток нули
        yield from zeros_gen

    cnt = 0
    zeros_gen = gen_zero()
    for val in gen_values_with_gaps(zeros_gen):     
        if size != None and cnt >= size:
            break
        yield val
        cnt += 1
```

#### Вариант №2

```
def gen_stream(size, elements, extractor=lambda x: x): 
    elem_iter = iter(map(extractor, elements))
    pos, val = next(elem_iter, (None, None))
    cnt = 0 
    while size == None or cnt < size:
        if cnt == pos:
            yield val 
            pos, val = next(elem_iter, (None, None))
        else:
            yield 0
        cnt += 1
```

---

**Тестирование**

```
test_gens = [
    gen_stream(9,[(4,111),(7,12)]),
    gen_stream(None,[(4,111),(7,12)]),
    gen_stream(None, []),
    gen_stream(9, [])
]

for gen in test_gens:
    for cnt, v in enumerate(gen):
        print(v, end=' ')
        if cnt > 30:
            break
    print()
```

**Output**

```
0 0 0 0 111 0 0 12 0 
0 0 0 0 111 0 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```