# Как создать генератор для объекта?

Tags: python

Функция создает генератор для этого объекта. Генератор потока должен быть равен исходному потоку.

```
gen = gen_stream (9, [(4,111), (7,12)])

list (gen) [0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0]
```

Вот код:

```
from itertools import count


def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    sorted_iterator = iter(sorted_iterable)  # transform to iterator
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    try:  # get first value
        current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        current_extracted_record = None
    for i in iterable:
        if current_extracted_record:
            if i == current_extracted_record[0]:
                try:  # get next value
                    yield current_extracted_record[1]
                    current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
                except StopIteration:
                    current_extracted_record = None
            else:
                yield 0
        else:
            yield 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen = gen_stream(9, [(4, 111), (7, 12)])

    print(list(gen))
```

Выводит это:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0]
```

Как решить данную задачу, не изменяя входные параметры и без использования "try"?
Есть ещё такой вариант без использования "try", но тут  другая проблема....
`sorted_iterable = dict(map(extractor, sorted_iterable))` тут словарь, и просто так dict же не удалишь, а надо iterable

```
from itertools import count
 
def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    sorted_iterable = dict(map(extractor, sorted_iterable))
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    for i in iterable:
        yield sorted_iterable.get(i, 0)
```

Повторюсь, нужно решить это как-то не изменяя входные параметры и без использования "try".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1146546/394322 ?

Answer (score 1):

`нужно решить это как-то не изменяя входные параметры и без использования "try".`

```
try:
    current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
except StopIteration:
    current_extracted_record = None
```

заменить на

```
for i in sorted_iterator:
    current_extracted_record = extractor(i)
    break
else:
    current_extracted_record = None
```

или короче

```
for current_extracted_record in map(extractor, sorted_iterator): break
else: current_extracted_record = None
```